# call event from form2 in form1

Tags: c#, winforms, events

hi
call event from form2 in form1?

for example :

The following code into form2 :

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
```

What to write in a form1?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you wanting to call the event? Will you know the sender and the Event Args?

Why don't you just create a public method in Form2 that Form1 is able to see?

Answer (score 0):

how about `form2.Form2_Load(this, null)`

Comment: It's a private method. He can't call it from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call private members of a class from outside it.

You can change the accessibility to `internal`, which will make it visible within the assembly - if your `form1` is in the same assembly.

Alternatively you can make it a `public` method, which would make it globally accessible.

However, you shouldn't call event handlers in such a manner - they are supposed to handle events that the declaring class raises.

For the sample code you gave, a better solution would be to create a public or internal method that can be called from this event handler:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod();
}

public MyMethod()
{
    MessageBox.Show("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

In order to call this method from `form1`, it needs to know about `form2`:

```
 // in form1
 Form frm2 = new Form2();
 frm2.MyMethod();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "principled way"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't raise an Event from outside a class.
The convention is that you call a `OnEventname` method in the class. Usually this method is protected (can't only accessed from the class itself or others that inherit from it)

```
// in form1
private void Method1()
{
    using (var form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.Show();

        form2.RaiseLoadEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

// Create this method in form2
public void RaiseLoadEvent(EventArgs e)
{
    OnLoad(this, e);
}


// The OnLoad method already exists in form 2 
// But it usually looks like this
protected void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    var eh = LoadEventHandler;
    if (eh != null) 
    {
       eh(this, e); 
    }
}
```

But I don't suggest to raise the LoadEvent, because It is raised only once after the creation of the form. More usual is to react to the Load event to modify the form.

```
privat void Method1()
{
    using (var form2 = new Form2())
    {
        // Add Event Handler
        form2.Load += new EventHandler(form2_Load);
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
    // Allways remove Event Handler to avoid memory leaks
    form2.Load -= new EventHandler(form2_Load);
} 

private void form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2.Text = "Hello from form1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form1 (the event publisher) should expose a separate, public event property for Form2 (the subscriber) to subscribe to.

For example: the form publishing the event will look like this:

```
public partial class Publisher : Form
{
    public event PostUpdateHandler OnPostUpdate;

    public Publisher()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new Subscriber(this).Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnPostUpdate != null)
        {
            OnPostUpdate(new PostUpdateArgs(textBox1.Text));
        }
    }
}

public delegate void PostUpdateHandler(PostUpdateArgs args);
public class PostUpdateArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string UpdateText;

    public PostUpdateArgs(string s)
    {
        UpdateText = s;
    }
}
```

The subscribing form looks like this:

public partial class Subscriber : Form
    {
        public Subscriber()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    public Subscriber(Publisher publisher) : this()
    {
        publisher.OnPostUpdate += new PostUpdateHandler(publisher_OnPostUpdate);
    }

    private void publisher_OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateArgs args)
    {
        this.Form2_Load(null, null);
    }

    private void Subscriber_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
}
```

When the user presses button1 on the publishing form, the subscribing form will execute the code associated with the delegate, resulting in a message box popping up with the message `http://stackoverflow.com`.